# Access modifier error - Although class is public

Tags: java

I have two classes `class A` and `class B` , When i tried to compile this program I am getting following compile time error.

> The type A.C1 is not visible

```
package com.abc;

public class A {
    static class C1 {
    }

    public static C1 member = new C1();
}
```

Class `B` declared in package `cde`

```
package com.cde;

import com.abc.A;

public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(A.member.hashCode());
        System.out.println(((Object)Api.member).hashCode()) //Working fine
    }
}
```

My query is why compilation fails with this error as my class and variable C1 is public

**PS: I don't want to change the API - I know changing C1 to public will fix my problem**

Comment: Your class `C1` is *not* public.

Comment: Tried the same code in Eclipse, by making the declaration of `static class C1` to `public` solves the problem.

Comment: @EJP- Why do you want me to change the API. I have edited the question and posted the answer as well please share your inputs

Comment: @LoneWolf I haven't said anything about changing the API. I am simply pointing out the error in your question. C1 is not public, and that's what the error message says, and you either have to make it public or adjust something else in your code.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler already stated the problem.

**The type A.C1 is not visible**

You may need to add `public` for your inner class `C1`

```
package com.abc;

public class A {
    public static class C1 {
    }

    public static C1 member = new C1();
}
```

Comment: please - check JSL for public access modifier .

Comment: @LoneWolf Check it yourself. This answer is correct. Your point?

Comment: @EJP- Kindly check my answer, this what i am lokking for

Answer (score 1):

You need to change scope of class C1 to public.

```
public class A {
    public static class C1 {
    }
   ...
}
```

C1 is visible only for classes in the same package as A1. So for classes in other packages to be visible you need to change the scope, or create a public interface/abstraction that will be public. And your implementation will stay in package scope.

According to the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html):

> Note: A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its
>   outer class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class.
>   In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class
>   that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging
>   convenience.

So your inner class A1.C1 behaves same as class A1, then it comes to visibility.